# Shared state in ES6 vs CommonJS modules

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, module, state, commonjs

I can share state via CommonJS modules, but not via ES6 modules.

I'm wondering why, and want to know how to share state via ES6 modules.

## CommonJS

main.js:

```
const shared = require('./shared.js');
shared.val = 2;
require('./child.js');
console.log('main.js', shared);
```

child.js:

```
const shared = require('./shared.js');
console.log('child.js', shared);
```

shared.js:

```
module.exports = {val:1};
```

Result:

```
$ node main.js
child.js { val: 2 }
main.js { val: 2 }
```

## ES6

main.mjs:

```
import shared from './shared.mjs';
shared.val = 2;
import a from './child.mjs';
console.log('main.mjs', shared);
```

child.mjs:

```
import shared from './shared.mjs';
console.log('child.mjs', shared);
export default undefined;
```

shared.mjs:

```
export default {val:1};
```

Result:

```
$ node main.mjs
child.mjs { val: 1 }
main.mjs { val: 2 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can share state in exactly the same way.

What you can't though is run code in between imports. They all should be at the top of your file because they are basically hoisted to the top.

If you change child to something like this:

```
import shared from './shared.mjs';

export default () => {
  console.log('child', shared);
};
```

And then run that after you've changed shared:

```
import shared from './shared.mjs';
import runChild from './child.mjs';

shared.val = 2;

console.log('main', shared);
runChild();
```

They'll both have `{ val: 2 }`.